# How Do You Configure A Custom Page To Use When Failing a Policy Check

Tags: asp.net-core

How do you configure a page that a user is redirected to when they fail a policy check?  I've seen Custom Authorization Policies here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/iauthorizationpolicyprovider?view=aspnetcore-6.0.  However I don't want to create a custom policy; the policy framework that comes out of the box is working fine.  However when it fails, I want to configure it to redirect the user to a specific page of my choosing.  Right now it shows a generic access denied error on a page using the original layout template that the project started with, not the one we are using for the site.

This is on ASP.NET Core 7.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to make this work by creating an IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler, as documented here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/customizingauthorizationmiddlewareresponse?view=aspnetcore-6.0.  In my case, I'm adding a specific Role claim, and if the user does not have that claim and tries to access a specific page, I want to return them to a custom error page that I designed.  The simplified set of steps are as follows:

1. I created a class that implements IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler:

   public class TeamsThingsAuthorizationHandler : IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler
   {

   ```
   private readonly AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler defaultHandler = new();


   public async Task HandleAsync(
       RequestDelegate next,
       HttpContext context,
       AuthorizationPolicy policy,
       PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
   {

       if (authorizeResult.Forbidden)
       {
           var fails = authorizeResult.AuthorizationFailure.FailedRequirements.ToList();

           if (fails.Any())
           {
               try
               {
                   //I'm looking for a failure caused by a user not having a claim I defined in a policy in Startup
                   ClaimsAuthorizationRequirement car = (ClaimsAuthorizationRequirement) fails[0];

                   //I'm making a small leap of faith here that if the issue is that the reason for the failure is missing the Role claim, then it's the one I want
                   if (car.ClaimType == ClaimTypes.Role)
                   {
                       //I then create the error info I want to send to my page
                       Models.UserErrorInfo uei = new Models.UserErrorInfo();
                       uei.ErrorMessage = "Sorry, you don't have access to the content you are trying to reach.  It's only for us.";

                       string redir = $"https://{context.Request.Host}{context.Request.PathBase}/home/ohno?" + 
                           $"ErrorNumber={uei.ErrorNumber}&ErrorMessage={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(uei.ErrorMessage)}&" + 
                           $"AdditionalInfo={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(uei.AdditionalInfo)}";

                       context.Response.Redirect(redir);
                       return;
                   }
               }
               catch (System.Exception ex)
               {
                   Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
               }
           }
       }

       // Fall back to the default implementation.
       await defaultHandler.HandleAsync(next, context, policy, authorizeResult);
   }
   ```
2. I registered my custom authorization middleware in Startup:

```js
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler, TeamsThingsAuthorizationHandler>();
```

3. In my controller, I unwrap the query string values and put them into the Model for the page:

```js
public ActionResult OhNo()
        {
            string errNum = HttpContext.Request.Query["ErrorNumber"];
            string errMsg = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(HttpContext.Request.Query["ErrorMessage"]);
            string addlInfo = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(HttpContext.Request.Query["AdditionalInfo"]);

            UserErrorInfo uei = new UserErrorInfo()
            {
                ErrorNumber = errNum,
                ErrorMessage = errMsg,
                AdditionalInfo = addlInfo
            };

            return View(uei);
        }
```

Now I can use my own layout page and create my own message for users.